# Pull changes and merge files from github using php?

Tags: php, git, github

I am looking at setting up a blog for all my plugins. All the plugins are hosted oh github.
because each plugin has all the information I would want to show in my blog already I want to try generating my blog pages automatically (and the demo pages for the plugins). I know how to setup post-receive hooks to get A ping when the repo gets pushed to. And I could download the entire zip of that repo but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way and was looking at pulling just the changes and merging them. Is this possible with php?

Comment: You could try out [shell-exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) if you have git installed on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Git.php](https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php) can do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Googled for a PHP+Git library? I did and found this: [PHP Git](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5310-PHP-Retrieve-project-files-from-GIT-repositories.html), and this [git-php](https://code.google.com/p/git-php/).

Comment: Yeah I did. The first library seems good. But the biggest thing I am looking for is the ability to merge the changes using php. Actually fetching just the changes is the easy part! Also. The links to the repository in your second link are broken. Already tried that one!